# Compare list to online database, javascript after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a big list of domain names that I want to check against the online database of http://www.checkdomain.com/.

I don't want to check one by one so I figured that I could use firebug to enter every website from my list in the input form, then submit the form and then save the domain in another text-file if it is available.

I have no problem with getting text in the input form and I use ".click()" with firebug to submit the form. But the javascript after the submit is not executed. I guess this is because javascript reloads with every refresh. Is there a workaround for this or does someone have any kind of clue how I can take on this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about using [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), or sites that accept a list of domains, or ...?

Comment: @NabilKadimi I would really prefer to program it

Comment: nope, checked it. you cannot do it using a get, and using a form redirects you to a new page.

Comment: @Thouartamazing So you saying it's impossible?

Comment: @Michiel: I disagree with the word "impossible," though someone might argue that it's overkill to use code for such a task.

Comment: @BrandonParmenter I also want to use method for this website: http://gamertagchecker.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with JavaScript/jQuery and iframes.

1. You need --of course-- to allow  cross origin requests [manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts) or with [an addon](https://www.requestpolicy.com/)
2. Write a HTML page that will hold the checkdomain.com iframe and your JavaScript/jQuery code that handles your operations (sending requests, grabbing values, saving data...)

Comment: Sounds complicated, is this link: http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls a good starting point? Or am I on the wrong path?

Comment: I understand that you already know your JavaScript, but that you are worried about it being dismissed after a page load. The only way to overcome this is to have your JS in a window and the other website in a child element (an iframe). The CORS doesn't constitute a big challenge for you, since you are can ignore it in your browser and you are not worried about other people that need to use your site/app...So my answer, you don't need to worry about CORS.